# How to keep entity properties data after save it on core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating an entity of UserEntity:

```
    let userEntity = UserEntity(context: managedContext)

    userEntity.username = user.username
    userEntity.name = user.name
    userEntity.personCode = user.personCode
    userEntity.personalData = XMLRegistrationData.toEntity(userPersonalData: user.registrations.registrationData)
```

and saving it on this property "loggedUser":

```
            let loggedUser = XMLUserData.toEntity(user: xmlUserData)
            print(loggedUser) // first print

            do {
                try self.context.save()

                print(loggedUser) // second print
            } catch {
                ...
            }
```

The first print results on this:

```
<UserEntity: 0x282b07a70> (entity: UserEntity; id: 0x28081c460 <x-coredata:///UserEntity/t78B51567-8104-4232-9BEA-062FBCB3CEEC3> ; data: {
    activeSession = nil;
    name = "FOO";
    personCode = 000;
    personalData = "0x280828020 <x-coredata:///UserPersonalDataEntity/t78B51567-8104-4232-9BEA-062FBCB3CEEC4>";
    username = 001;
})
```

But the second print result on this:

```
<UserEntity: 0x282b07a70> (entity: UserEntity; id: 0xd000000000840002 <x-coredata://C833ECD4-5D54-48C3-9860-B2E0781D08EC/UserEntity/p33> ; data: <fault>)
```

The UserEntity attributes is nil after saving it on the core data. The object is saved on the core data, I can fetch it using context.fetch, but loggedUser is changed.

Why that occurs? And how can I keep the data on loggedUser after it's saving, not needing to fetch it from core data after save it?

Comment: Data saved in core Data is assigned an ID using which you will get the Data from Core even after saving

Answer (score 0):

It's not `nil` it's a [`fault`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html). The data are still there. You can prove it by printing `loggedUser.username`

> Faulting reduces your application’s memory usage by keeping placeholder objects (faults) in the persistent store.

Comment: loggedUser.username returns nil. That's my point. I'm losing that data on the property. The data is saved on the core data. I can fetch that user from core data and get the username. But if I try to print loggedUser.username, without fetching from the core data, the loggedUser properties is nil. I'm trying to figure out why.